# Count the number of times distinct values occur in KEy-Value Pair using JAVA Spark API

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a grouped `JavaPairRDD<String,Iterable<String>>` which looks like this

```
(null,[null])
(01,[POGUpdateTenentKafkaListenerServiceImpl:, POGUpdateTenentKafkaListenerServiceImpl:, POGUpdateTenentKafkaListenerServiceImpl:, POGUpdateTenentKafkaListenerServiceImpl:, POGUpdateTenentKafkaListenerServiceImpl:, AMAN, POGUpdateTenentKafkaListenerServiceImpl:, POGUpdateTenentKafkaListenerServiceImpl:, POGUpdateTenentKafkaListenerServiceImpl:, POGUpdateTenentKafkaListenerServiceImpl:, POGUpdateTenentKafkaListenerServiceImpl:, POGUpdateTenentKafkaListenerServiceImpl:, POGUpdatrviceImpl:, POGUpdateTenentKafkaListenerServiceImpl:, POGUpdateTenentKafkaListenerServiceImpl:, POGUpdateTenentKafkaListenerServiceImpl:, POGUpdateTenentKafkaListenerServiceImpl:, POGUpdateTenentKafkviceImpl:, POGUpdateTenentKafkaListenerServiceImpl:, POGUpdateTenentKafkaListenerServiceImpl:, POGUpdateTenentKafkaListenerServiceImpl:, POGUpdateTenentKafkaListenerServiceImpl:, POGUpdateTenentKafkaListenerServiceImpl:, POGUpdateTenentKafkaListenerServiceImpl:])
(10,[POGUpdateTenestenerServiceImpl:])
(23,[POGUpdateTenentKafkaListenerServiceImpl:])
```

Now for each number i want to count the number of times a value occurs . For Example in this case i want the out to be like

```
01,POGUpdateTenestenerServiceImpl=23: AMAN=1
```

for the key 1.
How can this be achieved .

Answer (score 1):

scala implementation

```
input.map(r=>
    (r._1, r._2.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).toList)
    )
```

Comment: Thanks . But can you please give a java implementation as i am using java

Comment: sorry, i have never used spark java apis

Answer (score 1):

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<String>> pairRDD = ...;
JavaPairRDD<String, Map<String, Integer>> resultPairRDD = pairRDD.mapValues(new Function<Iterable<String>, Map<String, Integer>>() {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Integer> call(Iterable<String> arg0) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for(String s:arg0){
            int curCnt = countMap.containsKey(s) ? countMap.get(s) : 0;
            countMap.put(s, (curCnt+1));
        }
        return countMap;
    }
});
```

Comment: Use this java code it is converting your pairRDD to resultPairRDD<String, Map<String, Integer>>. Let me know if it helps